# hashCode as object ref in JDK 8

Tags: java, hashcode, object-reference

From what i know, [jdk 8 now](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html) is assigning as `hashCode` the memory address of the object.

And, `obj1 = obj2` returns true iff the `obj1` is `obj2`, i.e., they're sitting at the same memory location.

However, the following code executes the "else" part-- not the "then" part of the if-stat which is what i expect:

```
String h1 = "heya"; 
String h2 = new String ("heya");
System.out.println("hashCodes "+h1.hashCode()+" "+h2.hashCode()); 

if (h1 == h2) 
        System.out.println("yeah - the same ");  
else System.out.println("nope-- difft objects ");
```

What am i missing here?

TIA.

Comment: @Aeshang - that's another issue -- that's how they were to me too but i'll be wondering abt that once I get passed this. what ur saying is that instantiating a new string by-passes interning that value and I agree. however, run n see the hashCode values in the above code.

Comment: `String` != `Object`. Different `hashCode` implementation.

Comment: The tutorial is misleading. `hashCode` doesn't need to have anything to do with memory addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`h1` and `h2` are not sitting in the same memory location. You are calling a `new String("heya")` so the JVM will create a new instance of `String`. Therefore, `h1 == h2` is false. The `hasCode` is the same because it is based on the `char` composing the `String`.
Using `equals` method instead of `==` will return `true`.

Comment: forgotton abt String implementing its own hashCde. will accept ur ans when it allows.

Answer (score 0):

The String class overrides `hashCode()`.